# What is meaning this { logics } grammer in JS(not object)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I saw this code in reactjs open source in github
file : `react.development.js`

```
  {
    ReactDebugCurrentFrame.setExtraStackFrame = function (stack) {
      {
        currentExtraStackFrame = stack;
      }
    }; // Stack implementation injected by the current renderer.


    ReactDebugCurrentFrame.getCurrentStack = null;

    ReactDebugCurrentFrame.getStackAddendum = function () {
      var stack = ''; // Add an extra top frame while an element is being validated

      if (currentExtraStackFrame) {
        stack += currentExtraStackFrame;
      } // Delegate to the injected renderer-specific implementation


      var impl = ReactDebugCurrentFrame.getCurrentStack;

      if (impl) {
        stack += impl() || '';
      }

      return stack;
    };
  }
```

Suddenly it uses `{}` without initailize to object what is this grammer meaning and how is this grammer called?

Comment: erm ... which line of code do you not understand? can't see `{ logics }` anywhere in your code

Comment: i need the complete codes and the section U need to answer

Comment: oh, you mean that whole block of code is enclosed in `{}` ... it's a block of code I guess - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block#syntax

Comment: yes Jaromanda X was right. i meant block of code. thanks for reference link.

Answer (score 3):

It's a plain block.

```
  {
    currentExtraStackFrame = stack;
  }
```

is equivalent to

```
  if (true) {
    currentExtraStackFrame = stack;
  }
```

Using a block without a condition or loop is quite weird, but technically allowed. *Why* such code exists is a good question, and it's [because](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react/src/ReactDebugCurrentFrame.js) it's the result of transpilation - the *source* code that generates this is

```
const ReactDebugCurrentFrame = {};

let currentExtraStackFrame = (null: null | string);

export function setExtraStackFrame(stack: null | string) {
  if (__DEV__) {
    currentExtraStackFrame = stack;
  }
}

if (__DEV__) {
  ReactDebugCurrentFrame.setExtraStackFrame = function(stack: null | string) {
    if (__DEV__) {
      currentExtraStackFrame = stack;
    }
  };
  // Stack implementation injected by the current renderer.
  ReactDebugCurrentFrame.getCurrentStack = (null: null | (() => string));
  ...
```

When the source code is transpiled to a JavaScript bundle, if the `__DEV__` setting is true, in order to faithfully transpile the existence of a block, it appears that `if (__DEV__) {` is simply replaced with a plain block - which they might consider nicer than having to do a runtime check for the same thing (which would require a tiny bit of additional code to send over the network and a tiny bit of extra processing for clients).

Comment: thanks, but i don't understand why use plain block then. Condtion only needs for options i thought. if `{}` means always `if(true){}` that means basically always `{logics}` will make logics work.

Comment: Consider it to simply be an artifact of the transpilation process.